# Issue when executing a local script on a remote Unix machine

Tags: python, bash, scripting

I want to execute a local script on a remote Ubuntu machine - I have my local script setup like this:

```
ssh -i ~/my.pem remote_machine 'bash -s' < ./install.sh
```

and, in ./install.sh, I have multiple lines, some of which is reproduced here:

```
source activate mySrc
pip install <install from a pypri repo>
```

The error i get is

```
`bash: line 5: pip: command not found
```

I have confirmed that pip is installed on the remote server. But, I still get this error. Can you suggest why this could be happening?

Comment: Have you tried logging on the server and running those commands locally ?

Comment: Bruno, thanks for the question - Yes. I have confirmed that on the remote machine, the same command works, and the package is indeed downloaded from the pypri repository.

Comment: Add this line `set|grep PATH` into your `install.sh`, an see if `pip` is in your `PATH`.

Comment: @stovfl: Brilliant! I am banging my head why this was not thought of. But, great answer, and great catch. That was **exactly** the problem.  The moment i printed the path, the issue was that where pip was installed, PATH was not set... 

So, I am wondering: if 'bash -s' is passed via ssh, does it not get the environment variable from the $PATH variable? it has already been set on the remote server!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @stovfl. The problem is that when the ssh connection was established, the environment PATH variable was not getting set. Therefore, it did not have the information about the conda environment where pip was installed.

I just solved it by explicitly setting the path to where pip was installed!

[StackExchange UNIX & LINUX: How to guarantee availability of $BASH_ENV](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138577/how-to-guarantee-availability-of-bash-env)